# Numbering of newtheorem

Tags: numbering, theorems

Right now I have the following preamble

```
newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\let\oldthm\thm
\renewcommand{\thm}{\oldthm\normalfont}

\newtheorem{corol}{Corollary}[section]
\let\oldcorol\corol
\renewcommand{\corol}{\oldcorol\normalfont}

\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}[section]
\let\oldlem\lem
\renewcommand{\lem}{\oldlem\normalfont}

\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[section]
\let\olddefn\defn
\renewcommand{\defn}{\olddefn\normalfont}

\newtheorem{exa}{Example}[section]
\let\oldexa\exa
\renewcommand{\exa}{\oldexa\normalfont}

\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[section]
\let\oldprop\prop
\renewcommand{\prop}{\oldprop\normalfont}
```

that suppresses the italic font that is used by the standard newtheorem command. I am looking to change the way these theorems, lemmas etcetera are numbered. I want to have them numbered by section, using the same counter, so for instance:

Section 1

-- Subsection 1.1

---- Theorem 1.1

---- Corollary 1.2

Section 2

-- Subsection 2.1

---- Lemma 2.1

---- Definition 2.2

Whereas right now the numbering is:

Section 1

-- Subsection 1.1

---- Theorem 1.1

---- Corollary 1.1

Section 2

-- Subsection 2.1

---- Lemma 2.1

---- Definition 2.1

I have tried using a dummy variable as an answer to another question proposed, but I haven't gotten it to work. Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\let\oldthm\thm
\renewcommand{\thm}{\oldthm\normalfont}

\newtheorem{corol}{Corollary}[section]
\let\oldcorol\corol
\renewcommand{\corol}{\oldcorol\normalfont}

\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}[section]
\let\oldlem\lem
\renewcommand{\lem}{\oldlem\normalfont}

\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[section]
\let\olddefn\defn
\renewcommand{\defn}{\olddefn\normalfont}

\newtheorem{exa}{Example}[section]
\let\oldexa\exa
\renewcommand{\exa}{\oldexa\normalfont}

\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[section]
\let\oldprop\prop
\renewcommand{\prop}{\oldprop\normalfont}

\begin{document}

\section{First}

\subsection{A}

\begin{thm}
Theorem
\end{thm}

\begin{corol}
Corollary
\end{corol}

\section{Second}

\subsection{B}

\begin{lem}
Lemma
\end{lem}

\begin{defn}
Definition
\end{defn}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post a MWE (compilable, but minimal code) that shows your problem to help us help you.

Comment: Sure! Just a minute.

Comment: `\usepackage{amsthm}` and `\newtheorem{definition}[thm]{Definition}` should be easiest

Comment: @ChristianHupfer This adds an unwanted subsection to the numbering of everything that is not a theorem. Any way to remove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `amsthm` package: When defining a new theorem, you can instruct it to use a shared counter:

```
\newtheorem{⟨env name⟩}[⟨shared counter⟩]{⟨text⟩}
```

For more details, see the `amsthm` documentation: "3 Theorem numbering"

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corol}[thm]{Corollary}

\begin{document}

\section{sec}
\subsection{sub}
\begin{thm}
\end{thm}

\begin{corol}
\end{corol}

\section{sec}
\subsection{sub}
\begin{thm}
\end{thm}

\begin{corol}
\end{corol}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is no need for those redefs when `amsthm` is loaded, just use `\theoremstyle{definition}`

Comment: @daleif I just guessed the OP would use amsthm, now that there is a mwe...

Comment: Erh, no, that MWE does not give the replacement for the `\let\oldexa\exa
\renewcommand{\exa}{\oldexa\normalfont}`, add some text to the theorems to see. You'll need `\theoremstyle{definition}` the default is `plain` which has an italic body which the OP clearly does not want (for some reason)

Answer (score 2):

This is the way without `amsthm`, using the `Coupled Counters` feature from (well, my ;-)) package `xassoccnt`.

Define a counter group name, which is basically arbitrary, then populate the group with the relevant counter names.

I don't recommend the redefinition of the `\thm` etc. commands, however.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{xassoccnt}

\DeclareCoupledCountersGroup{TheoDefCorolLemma}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\let\oldthm\thm
\renewcommand{\thm}{\oldthm\normalfont}

\newtheorem{corol}{Corollary}[section]
\let\oldcorol\corol
\renewcommand{\corol}{\oldcorol\normalfont}

\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}[section]
\let\oldlem\lem
\renewcommand{\lem}{\oldlem\normalfont}

\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[section]
\let\olddefn\defn
\renewcommand{\defn}{\olddefn\normalfont}

\newtheorem{exa}{Example}[section]
\let\oldexa\exa
\renewcommand{\exa}{\oldexa\normalfont}

\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[section]
\let\oldprop\prop
\renewcommand{\prop}{\oldprop\normalfont}

\DeclareCoupledCounters[name=TheoDefCorolLemma]{thm,corol,lem,defn,exa,prop}


\begin{document}

\section{First}

\subsection{A}

\begin{thm}
Theorem
\end{thm}

\begin{corol}
Corollary
\end{corol}

\section{Second}

\subsection{B}

\begin{lem}
Lemma
\end{lem}

\begin{defn}
Definition
\end{defn}

\begin{prop}
Proposition foo
\end{prop}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Try `\begin{thm}[Fermat]`. Besides, I'm not sure what advantage this has over `\newtheorem{corol}[thm]{Corollary}`.

Comment: @egreg: The redefinition of the `theorem` starter macros is not the real issue here, in my point of view. The advantage is to prevent the usage of `\newtheorem{foobar}[foo]{foobar}` each time, but to controll its behaviour later on, with possible decoupling.

Answer (score 2):

If, for some reason, you don't want to use `amsthm`, you can more simply patch `\@begintheorem`.

You should define one main theorem and the other ones to be subordinate to it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@begintheorem}{\itshape}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corol}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{exa}[thm]{Example}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}

\begin{document}

\section{First}

\subsection{A}

\begin{thm}
Theorem
\end{thm}

\begin{corol}
Corollary
\end{corol}

\section{Second}

\subsection{B}

\begin{lem}
Lemma
\end{lem}

\begin{defn}
Definition
\end{defn}

\end{document}
```

However, using `amsthm` is simpler:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corol}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{exa}[thm]{Example}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}

\begin{document}

\section{First}

\subsection{A}

\begin{thm}
Theorem
\end{thm}

\begin{corol}
Corollary
\end{corol}

\section{Second}

\subsection{B}

\begin{lem}
Lemma
\end{lem}

\begin{defn}
Definition
\end{defn}

\end{document}
```

[image]